# How can I keep consistent sorting of events with different lengths in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

An image from the demo on the FullCalendar website may help:

[image]

Notice on the 10th "Long Event" is on top, but on the 11th it's not. How can these events be made consistent so they always appear in the same order when spanning across a weekend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bug in the system. Adam posted [here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=510&q=consistent&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) that he had accepted the request to be changed by start time. No word on where this has gone...